# Displaying nested tables

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

I am trying to display a table like this.
[image]

I've already looked at: [How to make nested table structure in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195398/how-to-make-nested-table-structure-in-angular)
and it already was a great help in getting closer to my goal.

Currently I'm trying something like this:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let groupRowData of selectedEmployee.skills;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subGroupRowData of groupRowData.subGroups; let $index1 = index">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let skillRowData of subGroupRowData.skills; let $index2 = index">
      <tr>
        <th *ngIf="$index1 === 0" [attr.rowspan]="groupRowData.subGroups.length + subGroupRowData.skills.length">{{ groupRowData.name }}</th>
          <th *ngIf="$index2===0;" [attr.rowspan]="subGroupRowData.skills.length">{{ subGroupRowData.name }}</th>
          <td>{{ skillRowData.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ skillRowData.rating }}</td>
      </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

But it does look like hot garbage... Softskills and Technical KnowHow are supposed to be Group A and B, Project and Support Subgroup A and B, Business Fields and Automotive Transmission and Driveline are supposed to be Subgroup C and D

[image]

Comment: Perhaps would be helpful if you showed the `selectedEmployee` variable.

Comment: It is just a nested list, that contains a datastructure like what I've shown in the first picture. But I've actually figured out!

Not sure if I should just delete the question because it is rather basic, or leave it up and answer it, because it might be useful for others

Comment: If it's solved, I'd say it's better to post it as an answer. You never know how it might help someone in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution to my particular problem, gonna post an answer just in case someone runs into a similar issue.

Short heads up, "selectedEmployee" is an instace of

```
    export class Entry {
      general: GeneralInfo;
      skills: SkillGroup[];
    }
```

in which SkillGroup is a nested data structure like this:

```
export class SkillGroup {
  name: string;
  subGroups?: SubSkills[];
}

export class SubSkills {
  name: string;
  skills: Skill[];
}

export class Skill {
  name: string;
  rating: number;
}
```

With that in mind, this produced the desired outcome:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedEmployee">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let groupRowData of selectedEmployee.skills;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subGroupRowData of groupRowData.subGroups; let $index1 = index">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let skillRowData of subGroupRowData.skills; let $index2 = index">
      <tr>
        <th *ngIf="$index1 === 0 && $index2 === 0" [attr.rowspan]="groupRowData.subGroups.length + subGroupRowData.skills.length">{{ groupRowData.name }}</th>
          <th *ngIf="$index2 === 0;" [attr.rowspan]="subGroupRowData.skills.length">{{ subGroupRowData.name }}</th>
          <td>{{ skillRowData.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ skillRowData.rating }}</td>
      </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Resulting in a table that looks like this:

[image]